# Open source Geoparsing tool for Java?

Tags: java, geolocation

I need to implement GeoParsing as a part of my project.I am currently doing it by code,looking up the input for possible locations. I read about some geoparsing tools available like Yahoo Placemaker;however the ones I have come across are only available in enterprise versions.Does anyone know for an open source geoparser?Or maybe some other faster alternative to finding locations in a text ?

Comment: What do you mean by _"geoparser"_? What should it provide?

Comment: It should be able to locate locations in the text provided. eg. Happy times in Chicago. For this text it should identify Chicago as a place and probably map it to US.

Comment: Will the places be specific to one country or world wide?

Comment: Not all the countries,but more than one country,not more than 5. India,US,UK are the major ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I answer a bit late. 
But I think CLAVIN (https://github.com/Berico-Technologies/CLAVIN) would be what you are looking for (you can use the Java API) and it's open source.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo placemaker is no longer free...

Problem is, whether you would do geoparsing (recognize which word is location word) or geoparsing and geocoding (which location it is on the map) all together..

If geoparsing only, CLAVIN is a descent software to use. However, geocoding is not very good compared to Yahoo! placemaker.

I think a better solution to your problem is to fork this project
https://github.com/weizh/geolocator-3.0

The software rationale is explained in this paper
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gelern/pdfs/geocoding.pdf

The performance is comparable to Yahoo! placemaker, and better than CLAVIN on geocoding.

Comment: For having testing all of them, CLAVIN was much faster and stable than geolocator. Yahoo Placemaker was much better than both, but Geolocator was significantly better than CLAVIN. But it was Geolocator 1.0, so I believe the new version is much better :)

Comment: Also a good thing is CLAVIN and Geolocator are local and can be used offline, so no query limit for example